# How does this sql IF statement work?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

Im trying to create a php page where logged in users can update their profile.
Ive found an example Im trying to stick to:

I receive the POST from the update form:

```
$id=$_SESSION['id'];
$info1=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['info1']);
$info2=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['info2']);
$info3=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['info3']);
```

The sql query to update the profile

```
$query=mysqli->query("UPDATE profiles SET 
info1=IF('$info1' = '', info1, '$info1'),
info2=IF('$info2' = '', info2, '$info2'),
info3=IF('$info3' = '', info3, '$info3')
WHERE id='$id'");
```

How does this short IF statement work?
I dont want to update the column if there is no input - is that what it does?
How would i add some criteria to the inputs? like length of the string etc.

Comment: You should catch and apply criteria in your PHP code before you create the SQL. Also those `IF`s aren't really necessary. When you build your query, just check for `empty()` (and other criteria) then add them to a string (or array and use `implode()`)

Comment: What @GerbenJacobs is saying is that instead of using `IF` in SQL, you should test them in PHP and just leave those assignments out of the SQL if the input field is blank.

Comment: But this is only a snippet, i have like 8 inputs - would it still be better practice?

Answer (score 3):

So, to clarify from Benio's answer which explains the IF() condition, in effect it is saying that for each column you are trying to update,

if the incoming $variable value is blank, replace the column with what it already had (ie: to not destroy it just because a blank value came in).  If there IS something other than blank (the other half of the IF() function), update the column with what the $variable is...

and obviously you have 3 different $ variables for each column of info1, 2, 3.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation! Do you have any inputs to the question about how to do the php for looking through the inputs/variables and check if it meets criteria? like length of the string.

Comment: @MacLuc, not specifically as I don't do php, nor how your system is structured, but I would have a class that processed validations against each type... maybe even if a generic function saying here is a string, and it can be up to X characters... But then you have considerations of some strings that may require min lengths too, or strip invalid/special characters (like only digits in a phone number, or no numbers within a person's name, etc), but that is too much to speculate on implementation.

Answer (score 2):

```
IF(CONDITION, STATEMENT if CONDITION is true) for 2 arguments
IF(CONDITION, STATEMENT if CONDITION is true, STATEMENT if CONDITION is false) for 3 arguments
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = sprintf('UPDATE %s SET', $table);

$rowdata = null;
foreach ($rows as $field => $value) {
  $rowdata[] = sprintf('%s = %s', $field, $value); // Escape the $value here!
}
$sql .= sprintf(' %s', implode(', ', $rowdata));
```

So enter your table name in `$table` and the data that you want to add as key-pair values in an associative array called `$rows` and you will end up with your query in `$sql`

Comment: can you explain the code a little? for instance the %s? :-)

Comment: `%s` is used with the `sprintf()` function. It's a placeholder for a string. Check out the documentation for sprintf: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php